# Rear 146cm hub axle (quick release) for a frame with 130mm Over Locknut dimension?

Tags: hub, rear-wheel, quick-release

I have rear wheel (freewheel) that I can reuse for an older bicycle (130mm between dropouts) .

As the source bicycle frame has more width than necessary for this hub, there are metallic washers that I can remove for the narrower width frame.

As the hub overpass the frame on sides, the quick release doesn't work.

Ideas?

- Add bolts on sides as for solid hubs?
- Add washer on sides so quick release can push on the frame?
- Any adapters or especial quick release?

Comment: These dimensions are mm, not cm

Comment: @RossMillikan for obvious minor errors like that, feel free to apply an edit directly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a standard axle hub, the viable choices are to either replace it with a proper 141mm axle or trim it down that way.

If it's not a standard axle, there is no great solution. Bulking up the dropouts with washers is about all you can do. Ideally use serrated ones.

Note that converting 135 freewheel hubs to 130 has costs. If you take 2.5mm from each side, you'll often have cog/frame interference unless it's 5/6spd. If you solve that problem by taking all 5mm from the non-drive side, you wind up with very low spoke tension on that side after the redish.